# Cycle2 and Firefox Image Blinking

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, jquery-cycle

I am trying to figure out what is going on with my jQuery Cycle2 slideshow ... the issue seems to lie within Windows 7 and FireFox combination, I haven't been able to recreate the issue in any other scenario.

The images all load fine, but even after the images are loaded, the transition between images, it loads a portion of the image and then one second later loads the rest. It's a little difficult to explain, so I've uploaded a video to help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euttwaR4iKk

Here's the first bit of my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Holland Engineering</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cycle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/caption2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".various").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 360,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'fadein',
            closeEffect : 'fadein'
        });
    });
    </script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Holland Engineering" /></div>
        <div id="logovert"><img src="images/logovert.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="nav">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">Who We Are</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="casestudies.html">Case Studies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearall"></div>
    <div id="banner" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-speed=1400 data-cycle-auto-height=1200:500 data-cycle-caption-plugin=caption2>
    <div class="cycle-overlay"></div>
        <img src="images/home/slide1.jpg" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lago Del Pino in Tyler, TX" alt="" />
        <img src="images/home/slide2.jpg" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wood County Electric Cooperative in Quitman, TX" alt="" />
        <img src="images/home/slide3.jpg" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Racquet &amp; Jog in Tyler, TX" alt="" />
        <img src="images/home/slide4.jpg" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centene in Tyler, TX" alt="" />
        <img src="images/home/slide5.jpg" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lindale ISD Performing Arts Center in Tyler, TX, Images courtesy of Alan Roberts, AIA" alt="" />
    </div>
```

And the only other pertinent code is these couple blocks of CSS:

```
    #banner {
        position: relative;
        width: 1200px;
        height: 500px;
        margin-bottom: 9px;
        top: -4px;
    } 
    #banner img {
        width: 1200px;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

The whole site can be previewed at http://holland.hansonimageworks.com. If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this issue, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a portion of the next image you are seeing.  It's the body background you see in the transition.  Looks like a weird opacity issue.  Try giving the #banner a background color.

Comment: I just did this, to see if it would alleviate the issue. The problem is that I am still experiencing the same issue. Now I just see a solid color instead of the body background behind the images, although they still have the same transitioning issue.

Comment: Yeah, try ditching 'data-cycle-auto-height=1200:500'.  If that doesn't work try removing the height and width css on the images.  If that doesn't work try setting the img position to absolute and the height and width to 100%.

Comment: I'd like to follow up on this ... I have tried all three of your suggestions, and I am still having the issue, regardless of combinations or all of the above. But thank you for taking the time to look into this. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having an issue with this. I believe it has something to do with Firefox rendering animating images. Since your slideshow has fixed dimensions, you can make your images backgrounds, which I've found fixes the issue. Anyone have any thoughts on a responsive fix?

HTML:

```
<div id="banner" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-speed=1400 data-cycle-auto-height=1200:500 data-cycle-caption-plugin=caption2 data-cycle-slides=">div">
<div class="cycle-overlay"></div>
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('images/home/slide1.jpg');" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lago Del Pino in Tyler, TX" ></div>
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('images/home/slide2.jpg');" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wood County Electric Cooperative in Quitman, TX" ></div>
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('images/home/slide3.jpg');" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Racquet &amp; Jog in Tyler, TX" ></div>
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('images/home/slide4.jpg');" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centene in Tyler, TX" ></div>
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('images/home/slide5.jpg');" data-cycle-desc="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lindale ISD Performing Arts Center in Tyler, TX, Images courtesy of Alan Roberts, AIA" ></div>
```

**NOTE** the `data-cycle-slides=">div"` attribute must be added to #banner, as cycle assumes `<img>` slides by default.

CSS:

```
#banner > div.slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will cycle the `<div>` elements, which will have your images as their backgrounds, achieving the same effect.